# How to add Include directories in Visual Studio while cross-compiling to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm working on a c++ project on my Raspberry Pi. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to cross-compile the project to my Raspberry. 
But when I try to compile the project, I get the error"cannot open source file" in lots of header files.

I already managed to compile simple projects, but now I need to Include Directories and I don't know the proper syntax to set, on Visual Studio's project properties page, the Include Directories to tell the compile where the header files are stored.

For the PCL library, e.g., I was able to include directories using '$(INCLUDE_PCL)'.
But when I try to include pi's directory '/usr/Include/ni' I can't correctly set the absolute path. Here's an screenshot of my properties page (https://ibb.co/G2dszrx). I haven't set the Linker directories yet, since I'm currently getting errors on the compiling phase.

Does anyone knows how to set absolute path to include directories correctly?

EDITED:
Trying to figure this out, I created a new project (Proj) in which I include the file 'try.cpp' stored in the raspberry's "home/pi/projects" folder. This project is in the "/home/pi/projects/Proj" folder.

In the project property page, I have:

- Configuration Properties>General>Remote Build Root Directory --> ~/projects
- Configuration Properties>General>Remote Build Project Directory --> $(RemoteRootDir)/$(ProjectName)
- C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories --> $(RemoteRootDir)

When I compile the project this path gets created correctly, and the project is saved at the correct place, even if go further into more folders in the remote build project directory, but it can't find the include file "try.h".

How can Visual Studio know where to save the project using '$(RemoteRootDir)', but is not able to add that path include directory?

Comment: Those Include Directories are deprecared, IIRC; I think you should use the prop deeper in the compiler settings.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your current problem, but maybe you find [this](https://visualgdb.com/) usefull when you work with VS and the Raspberry Pi. It works very good and it solves many problems for cross compiling in VS.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz You mean the >C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories?

Comment: @Kampi I already saw that tool, but its too expensive to use. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I managed to correctly add the Additional Include Directories, and Additional Libraries.

Firstly I was also using OpenNI, to work with the PCL. After many tries, I discovered that OpenNI was not correctly installed. So I managed to install it with apt-get.

Secondly, If you want to include the "/home/pi/someDIR" directory at the Raspberry device, just add "/home/pi/someDIR" to Visual Studio's additional include directories.

For you still trying to achieve this, Merlyn Oppenheim, from visual studio, set up a sample project using VS 2019 and Raspberry PI template -> https://github.com/merlynoppenheim/sample-rasp-inc-headers

For this sample project the Visual Studio properties page should have:

C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories = '/home/pi/projects/vcpkg/packages/sqlite3_x64-linux/include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)'

C/C++ -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories = '/home/pi/projects/vcpkg/packages/sqlite3_x64-linux/debug/lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)'

C/C++ -> Linker -> Input -> Library Dependencies = 'wiringPi;sqlite3;pthread;dl'