# wiringPi.h library not found, getting a build error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cross-platform, wiringpi

My code is throwing an error sayiung it can't find **wiringPi.h**. I thought that setting project **>** configuration properties **>** linker **>** Additional library directories to the place the header is contained would work. However, I still get this error:

> Error     cannot find wiringPi: No such file or
> directory Agresso C:\usr\bin\ld   1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <wiringPi.h>

const int thermistorPin = 0; // thermistor is connected to GPIO 0
const int B = 3950;          // B value of thermistor
const int R0 = 10000;        // R0 = 10kOhm
const int R_LIMIT = 100000;  // maximum value for R

double readTemperature()
{
    int a = analogRead(thermistorPin);
    double R = R_LIMIT * a / (1023 - a);
    double T = 1 / (log(R / R0) / B + 1 / 298.15) - 273.15;
    return T;
}

int main(void)
{
    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
        return 1;

    while (true)
    {
        double temperature = readTemperature();
        std::cout << "Temperature: " << temperature << " C" << std::endl;
        delay(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts? I am using windows subsystem for Linux.

I tried to link **wiringPi.h** via project configuration properties.

Program should compile.

Comment: `linker > Additional library` is for a **linker**, you get a compiler error. Looks for the "Additional includes” in the compiler settings.

Comment: Hi Robert, if the reply is helpful, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using visual studio to link the dll, I suggest you refer to the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170#to-add-the-dll-header-to-your-include-path).

In addition, this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883265/how-to-add-include-directories-in-visual-studio-while-cross-compiling-to-a-raspb) is also worth your reference.

> For you still trying to achieve this, Merlyn Oppenheim, from visual
> studio, set up a sample project using VS 2019 and Raspberry PI
> template -> https://github.com/merlynoppenheim/sample-rasp-inc-headers
>
> For this sample project the Visual Studio properties page should have:
>
> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories =
> '/home/pi/projects/vcpkg/packages/sqlite3_x64-linux/include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)'
>
> C/C++ -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories =
> '/home/pi/projects/vcpkg/packages/sqlite3_x64-linux/debug/lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)'
>
> C/C++ -> Linker -> Input -> Library Dependencies =
> 'wiringPi;sqlite3;pthread;dl'

Comment: All necessary details to solve the problem should be in the answer, not behind a link. Websites can be modified or removed and then this answer becomes useless.